# The proper way to customize values in a choice field type?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to output a choice (select) list, with the values coming from a related entity. In the Flight entity, there is a many-to-one relationship with the Airport entity. The Airport entity has several properties, such as city, country, codeIata. Right now, this is how the Type is created:

```
$builder->add('origin', 'entity', array('label' => 'Origin Airport', 'class' => 'FlightcaseBookingBundle:Airport', 'property' => 'codeIata'));
```

This works fine, and it will output a  element with the *Airport->codeIata* as the option labels and the *Airport->id* as values, like so:

```
<option value="1234">CDG</option>
```

But what I actually wanted is the choice list options to display a concatenation of 2 fields, namely the IATA code and then the airport name, e.g.

```
<option value="1234">CDG - Paris Charles de Gaulle</option>
```

So then I created a new method inside my Airport entity called getLongName(), which did this for me. Then I replaced the value of property of *codeIata* with *longName*.

This essentially does what I wanted. But to me this seems hacky, and not desirable, since an entity class is strictly meant to define the object itself. On top of that I cannot send any arguments to the getLongName method this way either (like $maxlength or so). So what would be the proper way of manipulating what's displayed in the  element? Would I need to create a Transformer class to do this, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Symfony 2.0.x, AFAIK the only solution would be implementing a new method:

```php
class Airport
{
    public function getChoiceLabel()
    {
        return sprintf('%s - %s', $this->codeIata, $this->name);
    }
}
```

Then use with entity form type:

```php
$builder->add('origin', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'Origin Airport',
    'class' => 'FlightcaseBookingBundle:Airport',
    'property' => 'choice_label'
));
```

An alternative would be implementing `__toString()`, but I don't like to globally say that the representation of the `Airport` object it's IATA plus its name.

If you are using Symfony 2.1 maybe that there is a better solution (read: closure) to accomplish this.

**EDIT**: I've checked the documentation for Symfony 2.1, and it seems that it's not yet possible:

> This is the property that should be used for displaying the entities
>   as text in the HTML element. If left blank, the entity object will be
>   cast into a string and so must have a __toString() method.